# Python string in another string with some generic (foo) characters

Tags: python, string, matching

Say `a = 'h.el.o'`, how can I check if a is included in another string, being '.' any character (any character, but just one different character per '.')?

For example a would be included in b = 'a**h**w**el**i**o**y' and it wouldn't be included in c = 'a**h**wq**el**i**o**y'

Comment: regex (re.search) seems to be perfect here.

Comment: @IvanChaer, yes, it would be a match. '.' could be any, but just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's a perfect candidate for regular expression module and the `re.search` method that looks for the expression in the whole string, `.` being the wildcard single character in regex (coincidence?):

```
import re

a = 'h.el.o'
b = 'ahwelioy'
c = 'ahwqelioy'

print(re.search(a,b) is not None)
print(re.search(a,c) is not None)
```

results:

```
True
False
```